# What are the sites where I can find games for Ubuntu for free?

Tags: 16.04, games, downloads

Can someone share a site where I can find free games that had been tested on Ubuntu 16.04?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Steam has many games tried and tested in Ubuntu and SteamOS (Debian based) among others.

Comment: if you like very simple games like me, you can search with  "apt-cache search <keyword>" for something inside the repositories you are connected with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search games in:

- [GamingOnLinux (website)](https://www.gamingonlinux.com)
- [Linux Game Database (website)](https://lgdb.org/)
- [Lutris (website and platform)](https://lutris.net/)
- [Penguspy (website)](http://www.penguspy.com)
- [PlayDeb.net (website)](http://www.playdeb.net)
- [Steam (website and platform)](http://store.steampowered.com/)